# How to fix Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ContextWrapper error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

the line "private void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap)" is giving me a Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ContextWrapper error and I don't know how to fix it. so can you please help me, thanks.

here is my code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               final Bitmap  bmWallpaper = loadImage(toPhone2);
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
               public void run() {
                  setWallpaper(bmWallpaper);    
               }
            });}}
        );
        t.start();
        break;
            }
        }

        private Bitmap loadImage(int id) {
            InputStream WP = getResources().openRawResource(id);
            Bitmap wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(WP);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), toPhone2);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
            return bitmap;
        }

        private void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
               try{
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(wallpaper);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You overrode a function but changed the scope.  You can only do that if you make it more visible, not less.  Fix the scope on the function and it will compile.

Comment: Use method not function.

Comment: More specifically, the Context class declares a method `public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap)` which does what you are trying to do (however, it's deprecated). You could either add `@Override` and change your method to public, or rename your method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are overriding the method setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap), which must be declared as protected or public (I guess public). Try to change the line for

```
public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap)
```

or

```
protected void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap)
```

depending on how the inherited method is defined.